# Powershell script to set sorting on hyperlink column SharePoint list view

Tags: infopath, hyperlink

here is the powershell script to update sort order on hyperlink field modify view

```
$spView = $list.Views["All Links"]
$spField = $list.Fields["URL"]
$spView.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='URL' Ascending='True'/></OrderBy>"
$spView.Update()
```

It displays properly in view(in sorting order). But when I go to Modify view it displays None in Sort Category

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks